# How to model matter in code

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

I've always had a passion for science, understanding and programming. Given my interests, I thought a cool thing to do would be to model real world theories in code (with visuals) so that others may see the inner workings of reality.

My idea is to start off at the atom (quantum mechanics may be difficult to model) and work my way upwards. In order to do this, I would need a more solid understanding of matter than I already have. For example, how exactly atoms bond in a mathematical sense as well as the forces that cause DNA's structure and the like.

My question is simple - where do I start if I want to accurately use the mathematics of matter to model the real world from atoms to DNA to metabolism? Where should my foundations begin? Do I have to start in QM's or can I survive off of simple atom-atom interactions?

Thanks a ton!

(I said `simple` a lot when in actuality, I realize this will be extremely difficult)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics

Comment: This is perfect, I'm going to dive right in! Thank you!

Comment: Here's a [fun review](https://www.google.lu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjABahUKEwiLgN747czHAhWBPhQKHQS7D6I&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdspace.library.uu.nl%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F1874%2F10480%2Ffrenkel_96_understanding_liquids.pdf%3Fsequence%3D3&ei=DeXgVcvFN4H9UIT2vpAK&usg=AFQjCNH_m2UAusVXZtV1eGhPX_IdmO0pFA) on the state of liquid simulations since its start in Los Almos labs, written by JP Hansen and Daan Frenkel. It covers a nice summary of the main ideas involved in computational physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that what you are proposing would be an extraordinarily challenging task! Simulating a single (non-hydrogen) atom accurately in time requires a huge amount of computational power which scales as roughly (simulation resolution)^(3*number of particles)! In computational biology, nearly all simulations are Newtonian based to avoid this.

I would suggest starting off with a simpler system such as the n-body problem where you simulate n massive particles interacting under the influence of their mutual gravitational attraction. Wikipedia has a very good overview of this subject and you can find many tutorials dealing with exactly this system online.

My PhD is on computational physics (specifically numerical general relativity) and this is exactly where I started. Once you have experience with these simpler systems you can gradually move up to more complex simulations of physical processes like heat flow and fluid dynamics, but it is good to start with something simple.

Here is a good set of resources for computational physics suitable to upper level undergrad:

http://www.phas.ubc.ca/~krs/PHYS410/syllabus.html

Comment: I was just reading about how simulations use Newtonian Physics from @alarge's comment on Molecular Dynamics. I could see why that would be the case as the number of forces, factors and particles would strain almost any computer. I appreciate the well thought out answer and I'm glad to say, I learned something new! I'm going to finish reading up on MD's and then dive into your link.

Thanks again!!!